# Inject service with class decorator

Tags: angular, typescript

Is it possible to inject a service with a class decorator?

Let's say I have a class (actually angular service) like this:

```
@Injectable()
@InjectHttp()
export class MyService {

   constructor() {
      console.log("MyService");
   }
}
```

Now I want a decorator which injects the Angular `Http` service into my class:

```
function InjectHttp() {
   return function(target: any) {
      /* Inject Http service here */
   }
}
```

Is this possible with decorators?

Comment: I doubt that this is possible in any programming language. **Decorator** are applied over to any property or class just to describe/change their behaviour. AFAIK Angular2 hijack `Component` class `constructor` for DI injection, I don't think so decorator can do that.

Comment: Even it was possible, how would you use the Http service in your class anyway. You cannot reference it since it will not be available. It's only adding (http: Http) in your constructor so it's not that much work i guess.

Comment: why not just add to constructor (myService:MyService) and use the service ?

Comment: I want to create a module of decorators with which I can configure services to consume REST endpoints. I have a solutions with a base class for the services but it would be more handy to configure all the REST services with decorators.